# rtsp streaming in iphone sdk and ipad

Tags: audio-streaming

can any one tell me is it possible to stream rtsp audio/video in iphone sdk and ipad application..i m having audio format but there is no link for appropriate information.so plz tell me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) streaming media framework for RTSP/RTP streaming. AFAIK there is a config file for iPhone included, you should also find some related postings in the liveMedia mailing list.